# How the javascript event function can prevent server side event function (button click)

Tags: jquery, .net, vb.net, client-side, server-side

If I have, say, an .aspx page that has a button called "btnProcess":

`asp:imagebutton id="btnProcess" onmouseover="src='siteart/addpayment2.gif'" tabIndex="13" onmouseout="src='siteart/addpayment1.gif'" Runat="server" Width="88" Height="22" ImageUrl="siteart/addpayment1.gif" AlternateText="Add Payment Button (CTRL + Plus(+))"`

With jQuery, if I wanted to link a function to that button when it's pressed, I could write something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('#btnProcess').click(function () {
               return validateFields();
        });
});
```

If `validateFields()` returns `False`, the code behind:

```
Private Sub btnProcess_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnProcess.Click
```

will **not** fire. Vice versa if `validateFields()` returns `True`

If I comment out `return validateFields();` the code behind will fire - if I never declare a function that will trigger on click with javascript, the code behind will fire (these scenarios makes sense)

My question is (and I may be asking it wrong, sorry in advance) ***why*** can the javascript button.click function prevent the code behind from firing when it returns false?

I've always learned to think of client-side and server-side code as individual pieces of logic that really don't intertwine like this.

I'm looking for something more than *"just because"* which is what I received from a coworker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET postback is done by a JavaScript function called `__doPostBack`, if you view the source of your page it looks like this:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Note: If you have ever had to determine which control caused a postback, then the `__EVENTTARGET` name should look familiar. In your code-behind you would get the name of the control which caused the postback like this: `Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");`

As you can see this submits the form to the server, which is what we call a postback.

Using `return false;` or `event.preventDefault()` short-circuits the call to `__doPostBack` and your postback doesn't happen.

Comment: Never thought I'd have a professional wrestler answer my question... :P, thank you, this is cut, clear, and to the point. One question though, is this snippet of javascript inserted into every .aspx served page?

Comment: Wow, you are first person to "recognize" me as the wrestler Karl Anderson! LOL Yes, it is inserted into every page, but if you are using Master pages, then it is just in the master page as that creates the shell for the content pages to run within.