# Return value ignored from Jquery function

Tags: jquery, events

I have a piece of jQuery that is attached to asp.net web forms front-end (the input controls of the form are wrapped with the standard asp.net AJAX panel) which has a three dropdown lists which have a piece of jQuery attached:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("select").change(function () {
        alert("Hi");
        return false;
    });
});
```

The dropdowns have a server-side change event attached by ASP.NET as you would expect to do the postback:

```
<select name="ctl00$leftContent$cmbPressureUnitsPo" tabindex="6" class="unit" id="cmbPressureUnitsPo" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$leftContent$cmbPressureUnitsPo\',\'\')', 0)">
            <option value="1">kPag</option>
            <option value="1000">Pag (N/m²)</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="0.001">MPag</option>
            <option value="0.14504">PSIg</option>
            <option value="10">mBarg</option>
            <option value="0.01">Barg</option>
            <option value="0.010197">kgf/cm²</option>
            <option value="0.010197">atg</option>
            <option value="0.0098692">atmg</option>
            <option value="7.5001">torrg (mmHg)</option>
            <option value="101.97">mmH₂O</option>
            <option value="0.29528">inHg</option>

        </select>
```

The only problem is that the return false does not suppress the server-side event as i would expect!  If i implement a normal javascript function that returns false it does, what am i missing?

I have also tried event.PreventDefault with no effect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the `__doPostBack` method is wrapped in a `setTimeout` bound to the onchange handler.

```
<select ...  onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$leftContent$cmbPressureUnitsPo\',\'\')', 0)">
```

Your event handler (bound to the `select` element via jQuery) will be called separate from that (and my guess, before, given how setTimeout works - but you never know... the quirks of timers)

Comment: Thanks Jack, you are quite right there, it seems setTimeout guarantees the DOM is actually loaded better it seems than any other method - solved a couple of problems this week just by wrapping code is a zero interval timer!

Comment: @mmacneill123 - Yep - you're right, it does! (Although, I have seen a few quirks with Mobile Safari where even setTimeout doesn't guarantee DOM changes are present... weird stuff!) Were you able to get your issue addressed?

Comment: Yes Jack, just wrote it all in jQuery!  Copy and pasted the generated ASP.NET code from the markup, set Autopost=False so that ASP.NET no longer emits it and then attached the event manually.  Think i am getting confused between normal javascript handlers and jQuery!!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `onchange` in the HTML runs *first*, before your jQuery-bound event runs.  You can't prevent it from running, because it already has.  What you need to do is *remove* the HTML-bound event before adding one via jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $select = jQuery('select'),  // Cache jQuery selector
        HTML_event = $select.prop('onchange'); // Backup original event

    $select.removeProp('onchange');  // Remove original event

    $select.change(function(e){
        alert("Hi");

        //HTML_event.call(this, e.originalEvent); // If you want to call the original event
    });
});
```

Another solution could be to save the timeoutID, then call `clearTimeout` on it.

```
<select onchange="window.selectTimeout = setTimeout(function(){}, 0)">
</select>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    jQuery('select').change(function(e){
        alert("Hi");

        clearTimeout(window.selectTimeout); // clears the timeout
    });
});
```

Comment: Not convinced here!  The alert does show as I would expect, returns and then the page reposts!  There are other examples on stack that are the behaviour I am after, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002368/  I know I can work around this by removing the event and adding it back in, that is what I have done elsewhere but just puzzled why the behaviour seems so different!

Comment: @mmacneill123: In your example, when you change the value, the first event to be triggered is the `onchange` set in the HTML.  That calls that `__doPostBack` function in a `setTimeout.`  That timeout means that the browser will run your jQuery-bound event, then come back to the `__doPostBack` later.  So, then your event runs, and the `alert` opens (which pauses all other JavaScript execution) until it closes.  You can't "prevent" the `onchange` since it's already done.  When the alert closes, the browser goes back and runs the `__doPostBack` from the timeout.

Comment: P.S. there are a few bad practices at play in the `onchange`.  1) Don't add `javascript:` in the `onchange` (it doesn't do what you think it does), 2) Don't pass a string to `setTimeout` (it calls `eval`).

Comment: P.P.S. I've never used APP.NET, so I don't know how `__doPostBack` works or is set up, but I do know JavaScript :-)

Answer (score 0):

The actual solution I used was to create a single jQuery procedure that incorporates the ASP.NET generated postback.  By removing Autopost=True from the ASP.NET markup you can control precisely what is going on and still call the ASP.NET callback but write it in jQuery instead.